# How to gracefully refresh an aiohttp Client Session

Tags: python, rest, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am making API calls with a configured `aiohttp.ClientSession()`. After a certain period of time, the API requests that I make another post request to refresh some tokens. However, I want to make sure I am doing this as appropriately as possible.

Hard to mock-up a working example without sharing a few hundred lines of code but below is my simplified code and thought process. I do use a class to maintain state of my tokens, session, etc. but want a way to refresh my session when I hit a certain period of time, then retry for the latest request and continue on with the rest.

Currently I am seeing successful behavior but receive some warnings from aiohttp such as:

`unclosed client session` and `unclosed connector` so want to make sure I can close and re-open the refreshed session gracefully.

```
import time
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class Request:
    def __init__(self, url: str, method: str="get",  payload: str=None, headers: dict=None):
        self.url: str = url
        self.method: str = method
        self.payload: str or dict = payload or dict()
        self.headers: dict = headers

class Response:
    def __init__(self, url: str, status: int, payload: dict=None, error: bool=False, text: str=None):
        self.url: str = url
        self.status: int = status
        self.payload: dict = payload or dict()
        self.error: bool = error
        self.text: str = text or ''

def refresh_session() -> aiohttp.ClientSession:
    """
    Method to refresh our tokens for authentication. This will return a refreshed aiohttp ClientSession with new headers (that have the new refreshed tokens). 
These are maintained as class attributes, so when _fetch is called again, it will use the classes "self.client_session"
    """
    refresh_tokens: dict = {
        'accessToken': tokens['accessToken'],
        'refreshToken': tokens['refreshToken']
    }
    # Function that makes post request to get JSON of tokens for more api calls
    tokens: dict = refresh_tokens(tokens=refresh_tokens).tokens
    
    # Recreate headers and return new Client Session
    headers: dict = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {tokens['accessToken']}"
    }
    return aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers)

async def _fetch(client_session, request: Request) -> Response:

    async with client_session.request(request.method, request.url, params=request.payload) as response:
        # If we have been logged in for login_time + 10 seconds, refresh our session with new post request
        if time.time() >= self.login_time + 10:
            print("Refreshing tokens...")
            client_session: aiohttp.ClientSession = refresh_session()
            return await _fetch(client_session, request) # Retry with refreshed session
        
        # Request and response processing below here
        try:
            text = await response.text(encoding='utf-8')
            content: dict = await response.json()
            response.raise_for_status()
            return Response(request.url, response.status, payload=content)
        except aiohttp.ContentTypeError:
            # Exception handling stuff
```

Comment: One solution would be create one parallel asyncio task where you periodically refresh the token every 10 seconds - and don't create new ClientSession every time.

Comment: Interesting idea! In reality I only have to refresh every 30 minutes but I was testing with 10 seconds to understand. I think I ultimately figured out my initial idea (just had to move some code around), but your idea makes a lot of sense.